# Disable/Remove Text Select Handle from EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

When user click on EditText the cursor comes up with the Text Select Handle.
Text Select Handle can move around to a different position in the field.
Text Select Handle is

[image]

Is there a way you can remove that so it does not show up?

Comment: Along with applying the answers given. You should also rethink about design that why on first place you want to hide this. I do not prefer hiding such things which platform added for some reason and user are habitual of using those.

Comment: @Javanator I want to hide Text Select Handle because on tapping this PASTE button appeared.So I want to remove that functionality.

Comment: Is PASTE button is causing a harm. Its a handy thing. Don't you think so

Comment: In enterprise scenarios one would like to hide all the fancy system's actions for security reasons and unified experience.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To resolve this issue i have created an empty image in shape.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle" >

 <size
    android:height="0dp"
    android:width="0dp" />

 </shape>
```

and just use this image in edit text

```
 android:textSelectHandle="@drawable/your_empty_image"
```

Comment: Thank you deepak.This solution worked. Text Select Handle is not appearing now.

Comment: NB we found that this solution can cause a crash on Sharp manufactured Aquos/Docomo devices. - java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.updateDrawable(Editor.java:4338) -

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. Nexus 10 API 27. Although the handles no longer appear, one can still click just below the input text and context menu will pop up.

Answer (score 3):

A great solution was provided by @Deepak Goel, but this approach has one downside.
The "Text Select Handle" is disabled permanently for the given EditText.

Another approach is to call clearFocus() and then requestFocus(). It does the work, but it does not seem optimal. If someone dives deeper in the Android sources, he may find a more optimized solution though.

Answer (score -1):

For QTableWidget (didn't need or test on anything else so far), this solved the issue for me:

```
 #idef Q_OS_ANDROID
   table->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
   table->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
//   table->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
 #endif
```

The statement that is commented out is to remove any selection, while the other two statement still allow cells selections, but removes the text selection handle in cells.