# android - disable to popup paste button when longclick in Webview or Edittext

Tags: android, button, webview, android-edittext, paste

When longclick in edittext or textbox in webview **without selecting text**, Only one button appears named "paste".

I want to override this button but fail to find how to do it.

So I changed plan to make not to show up this button.

Any ideas?

paste button is [image]

Thanks

Comment: This might be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745986/disable-remove-text-select-handle-from-edittext-in-android

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I want to keep longclick with text selection.

Comment: Questions about that paste popup have been asked before, and I've yet to see a solution, so I just went digging through some source code. Accessing that in any way, whether to alter it or to disable it, would not be a simple task. The exact implementations vary between Android versions, as well, so you'd have to account for all the different versions you support. There might be some simple trick I haven't thought of yet, but at the moment, it looks like it'd take quite a bit of work to accomplish that.

Comment: I just want to support above 5.0 version(Lollipop). I agree that it looks like a simple thing.... but can't find solution. Is it possible that this function is not supported by API?